# I have followed the tutorial of Scrapy but there is no selected info been printed

Tags: scrapy

I am a beginer of the Scrapy and I followed the offical tutorial to learn.
http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html 
I do exactly as what is on the website.when I try to print the site on the screen there is no related info been printed.
Here is my code:

**items.py**

```
class DmozIterm(scrapy.Item):
    #define item for Dmoz
    title=scrapy.Field()
    link=scrapy.Field()
    desc=scrapy.Field()
```

**domzSpider.py**

```
import scrapy
class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//ul/li'):
            title = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            link = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            desc = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            print title, link, desc
```

---

## Finally I found the reason,why I can not get the scrapied info on the terminal:

It is the directory where I run command `scrapy crawl dmoz` is not the root directory of my Scrapy project. Hoping this stupid mistake can been voided for others by the post!

Comment: Scrapy's tutorial is a bit outdated for dmoz.org see my answer for related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243009/scrapy-tutorial-example/39243432#39243432

Comment: yeah, thanks to you I have checked the site, That's true,They changed the html. Even though I changed my code, I still have the same output on the terminal, which I mean I have not seen any expected info about the 21 sites on the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the html of the site changed, please try this:

```
for sel in response.xpath('//div[@id="site-list-content"]/div'):
    title = sel.xpath('./div[@class="title-and-desc"]/a/div/text()').extract()
    link = sel.xpath('./div[@class="title-and-desc"]/a/@href').extract()
    desc = sel.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "site-descr")]/text()').extract()
    print title, link, desc
```

Comment: yeah, thanks to @Granitosaurus I have checked the site, That's true,They changed the html. Even though I replaced mine code with yours, I still have the same output on the terminal, which I mean I have not seen any expected info about the 21 sites on the terminal.

Comment: but If I run `scrapy shell "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/"`on the root directory, and use `response.xpath('//div[@id="site-list-content"]/div'` I can get the info!  I thought that's weird!!

Comment: In my case it works, maybe you debug using this

    from scrapy.shell import inspect_response

    def parse(self, response):
        inspect_response(response, self)
        ....

Check it here for more details
https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/05/18/scrapy-tips-from-the-pros-may-2016-edition/