# How to get link text from this XPath?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Using the Python library Scrapy, I do the following:

```
scrapy shell "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/"
```

From there I'd like to get individual link + text of each returned item:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="title-and-desc"]/a')
```

However, only links are being returned and not text. Here's a sample of what's returned:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="title-and-desc"]/a')
[<Selector xpath='//div[@class="title-and-desc"]/a' data=u'<a target="_blank" href="http://www.brpr'>, <Selector xpath='//div[@class="title-and-desc"]/a' data=u'<a target="_blank" href="http://www.dive'>, <Selector xpath='//div[@class="title-and-desc"]/a' data=u'<a target="_blank" href="http://rhodesmi'>,
```

I can loop through the above results, where `i` is the variable for each iteration:

```
i.xpath("text()").extract_first(),
i.xpath("@href").extract_first()
```

But only the `@href` values are returned. This makes since because there is nothing for `text()` to retrieve in the results. What needs to change so I can also get the accompanying link text?

For reference, the full Scrapy example is coming from here: [Scrapy Tutorial Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243009/scrapy-tutorial-example).

Answer (score 0):

It's because the text you are looking for is in the child node `div`:

```
<div class="title-and-desc">
  <a target="_blank" href="http://www.network-theory.co.uk/python/intro/">
    <div class="site-title">An Introduction to Python </div>
  </a>
<div>
```

You can get all text of a node (with the text of it's children) by prepending `//` to it, i.e. `//text()` instead of `text()` or just go with explicit xpath `a/div/text()`.

Try:

```
links = response.xpath('//div[@class="title-and-desc"]/a')
for l in links:
    # url:
    print(l.xpath('@href').extract_first())
    # text with explicit xpath:
    print(l.xpath('div/text()').extract_first())
    # or with all text elements with relative //text:
    print(''.join(l.xpath('.//text()').extract()).strip())
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem since getting only text means not getting the URLs. I did try `i.xpath("//text()").extract_first()` but that didn't work.

Comment: Another useful option is to use XPath's `string()` or `normalize-space()`: `for l in links: print(l.xpath('normalize-space(.)').extract_first(), l.xpath('@href').extract_first())`